# Changing DOM content of konva container causes crash?

Tags: dom, javascript-objects, konvajs, konva

I try to save the content of my last konva stage object in a Map in window object. My original aim is to minimize the loading time when I want to open the same page that has been drawn. Things are going well within my own frame. However, when I load my frame which has Konva content in another window (which becomes the parent of my Konva frame), the konva frame crashes and the console does not show any errors.
[image]

My code snipplet looks like this:

```
 var xjGraph = cachedGraphObject; //Konva graph that already drawn, loaded from a js Map in parent window
 var containerDOM = document.getElementById(oldId);
 var konvaJsContent = xjGraph.getStage().content; //get the div of "konvajs-content" class
 var oldChild = containerDOM.firstChild;       
 oldChild.remove();
 containerDOM.appendChild(konvaJsContent); //remove the old div of "konvajs-content" and replace it with the one that I want to show; I could use replaceChild() here, but I get the same result
```

PS: If there is another way to save a stage in browser and load it when I need it for later use, please kindly help. Very much appreciated!

Comment: See https://konvajs.org/docs/data_and_serialization/Serialize_a_Stage.html

Comment: Have you tried using multiple Konva container elements ? So leaving the Konva container for an out-of-view element with css display none and adding new container elements for each new stage you have to display. Switching would then be a case of manipulating which is currently in view.   The overhead of maintaining the hidden stages would likely be similar to the cost of storing them as variables as per your current approach.

Comment: Ok，I can give it a try.Thanks

Comment: What was the result ?

Comment: I tried some other approach, trying to cache image of stage first. I'll get back to your method and compare both approaches.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat Hi, I implemented your approach, but when I switch divs, I get a blank one when I want to visit a stage that was visited before.

Comment: However, I can manage to switch divs when there is only a static image inside the container